# Android Room order by when field is null

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I use **Room Persistence Library** to store contact information.
I want to retrieve contacts based on last name and first name.

The problem is that contacts without the last name and first name ( null ) are received at the top of the list.
How do I query to get them at the bottom of the list?

here is my query:

```
select * from CacheContact order by lastName asc,firstName asc LIMIT :count OFFSET :offset
```

CacheContact object:

```
@Entity
public class CacheContact {

    private String expireDate;

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private long userId;
    private String lastName;
    private Boolean blocked;
    private long creationDate;
    private String profileImage;

    @Embedded
    private LinkedUser linkedUser;
    private String cellphoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String uniqueId;
    private long notSeenDuration;
    private boolean hasUser;
```

full dao method:

```
@Query("select * from CacheContact order by lastName asc,firstName asc LIMIT :count OFFSET :offset")
    List<CacheContact> getContacts(Integer count, Long offset);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
select * from CacheContact order by lastName is null or lastName='', lastName, firstName is null or firstName='', firstName LIMIT :count OFFSET :offset
```

The above query also checks for empty string value.

From [SQLite Release 3.30.0](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_30_0.html) onwards, you can also use [NULLS LAST](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#nullslast), so you can do something like:

```
select * from table order by column_name NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: can you explain more about this? is null or lastName=''

Comment: @HiddenCoder7 it is checking if column is null or if it an empty string, if you don't want the empty string part you can remove the `or` part from the query

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from CacheContact 
order by case when lastName is null or firstName is null then 1 else 0 end, 
lastName asc, firstName asc LIMIT :count OFFSET :offset
```

Comment: thanks but the contact with null firstName and lastName moved from first to third position with this query but this answer worked more accurate and send that contact to the end:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61484232/5646338